# Inherit from a non-abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have several classes which inherit from a BaseClass which has an abstract method called GetData. In one of them I want to basically inherit from again and provide use a new method called GetArticles which I call from GetData. Here's the code.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    internal abstract void GetData();
}

internal class FirstClass : BaseClass
{
    internal override void GetData()
    {
        // calls GetArticles
    }

    protected void GetArticles()
    {
    }
}

internal class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
    protected new void GetArticles()
    {
    }
}
```

`GetArticles` is never called in `SecondClass`. It calls the one in `FirstClass`, even though my object is of type `SecondClass`. I can't make `GetArticles` in `FirstClass` `Abstract` because I want to use `FirstClass` in its own right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `new` does not override a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare `GetArticles` in your `FirstClass` as virtual.  In the second class remove `new` and add `override`

Answer (score 8):

Your method has to marked as `virtual` in `FirstClass` and overriden using `override` keyword in `SecondClass`.

```
internal class FirstClass : BaseClass
{
    internal override void GetData()
    {
        // calls GetArticles
    }

    protected virtual void GetArticles()
    {
    }
}

internal class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
    protected override void GetArticles()
    {
    }
}
```

`new` modifier hides the underlying virtual method, which is not what you want. Check [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 6):

Make `GetArticles` virtual.

```
protected virtual void GetArticles()
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Normal Class can not contain abstract method.Whereas abstract class can contain normal method.
If a normal class inherit abstract class and hold any abstract method than must be override due to inheritance in derived class.

Comment: An example would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't think this addresses his quesiton.